# Google Workspace Marketplace: Apps with multiple App types configured in Marketplace SDK

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace-add-ons

I have a google docs addon published on Google workspace marketplace, recently I received an email from google which mentions that my addon is violating below mentioned policy.
[image]

I am unable to understand which configuration google want me to change in google console. could anyone with experience in this issue/configuration help me out please.

Edit: My Appscript.json

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is inside the `Google Workspace Marketplace SDK` configuration, what you need to do is the following:

1. Access to [GCP](https://console.cloud.google.com).
2. Select the project link to your add-on.
3. Search for `Google Workspace Marketplace SDK`, and select the first option.

[image: Google Workspace Marketplace SDK]

4. Click `Manage`.
5. Under `App configuration`,  search for `App Integration`.
6. You need to select only one option for the app, if you have `Google Workspace Add-on` or remove any other option different to `Docs Add-on`.

[image: App Integration]

This is because if you select `Google Workspace Add-on` this will deploy the add-on for all the Google Services even when the app is not meant to be use with the other Google services, and in your case (based on your description) the Add-on only works for Google Docs.

Base on the Google Workspace documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/overview#list_app_integrations_together)

> Some app integrations can be combined in your app listing. For
> example, if your app enhances the functionality of Sheets and is also
> accessible as a web app, you can publish an app listing that includes
> a Sheets add-on and a web app that’s added to the Google apps menu
> [image: apps] across Google Workspace products.

You can read the following documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/list-multiple-app-integrations#before_you_add_multiple_app_integrations), with more information about things to consider if you want to use `multiple app integrations`.

Comment: thanks a lot Giselle for detailed answer, Yes that's exactly where I thought the issue would be when I was first looking into the app configurations but as I checked only one checkbox was selected in App integration section which is Docs Addon. 

Is there any other place from where App Integrations are set?

Comment: Have you review in the Google Apps Script [manifest](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests#editing_a_manifest)? You can review this by accessing to the add-ons "Apps Script," and select `Project Settings` > `Show "appsscript.json" manifest file in editor`. Return to the editor `<>`, and select `appsscript.json`. Review you if you added the `addOns` field.

Comment: You can read more about that manifest field [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest#:~:text=%C2%A0%20%7D%0A%7D-,Fields,-addOns), and [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/addons).

Comment: I just checked my appscript.json, it doesn't have  "addOns" field. I have edited my question to add appscript.json snapshot as well.

Comment: It seems odd, to my knowledge those are the only places where you can set up the app configuration. If you reply to the `Trust & Safety team` with the screenshots of the `manifest`, and your `App Integration` page, stating that you haven't configure Multiple App types, they might provide you more information of any other place that might affect app configuration or review if there was some kind of mistake reviewing your application.